# Codeigniter username in url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm trying to create user profiles for my site where the username is in the URL.

But how i can do it?

For example   http://www.site.com/barackobama or else.

Comment: Have you tried Googling `Codeigniter username in url`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow [CI's URI routing guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

I would suggest to use a route such as (for example):

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "user/view"; // matched by www.site.com/user/barackobama
```

instead of

```
$route['(:any)'] = "user/view"; // matched by www.site.com/barackobama
```

to avoid conflicts between routes.